# A fresh SVN not pulling out all changes

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, partial, svn-checkout

I have a repository that I'm checking out from my SVN server onto Windows XP, and when it pulls down I don't have all the changes.  There are several partial change sets when I look over the incoming changes as well as some whole change sets that aren't checked out.  I am pulling head so I should get all of the changes.  However, when I do an update on the project it still doesn't pull down the changes.  What the heck is going on here?  I've also noticed that once I check out the project I don't have any .svn directories.  Could the .svn directories be stored somewhere else so when I do a full checkout it's using those folders or cached information causing the partial checkouts?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you perform the initial checkout using IntelliJ IDEA, not some other client, as current IDEA version is [not compatible with SVN 1.7 working copies yet](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/12/subversion-17-support-update/).

If the clean checkout from IDEA doesn't resolve the problem, delete IDEA `system/vcsCache` directory and update the project again ([see the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) to find it on your system).

You can also [try more recent build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11+EAP) with some SVN related fixes.

There must be `.svn` directory in each project subdirectory, note that they are not shown in the project view, use your favorite file manager to verify it. Also verify that the checkout root is mapped to **Subversion** in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Version Control` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are checking out the path you want and also, that you are indeed doing a checkout rather than an export. Otherwise, you should see everything that ought to be there and every working copy will have it's own `.svn` meta data folder, and in all folders ( this is changed in 1.7 so that the `.svn` will only be in the root of the working copy)